Render ModuleNotFoundError
I am trying to build a simple web app to learn a language with key cards on the go. The database is run with sqlalchemy and the app works flawlessly on my local host. But on render, where I host the web app, the error message "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask_sqlalchemy'" keeps popping up.
I've rehosted the app from scratch and updated the requirements several times, what can I do to resolve this?

Is flask_sqlalchemy installed on the host where you are running your app? Is pip install being run against the requirements file upon deployment?

Yes to all of Ali's inputs.

The appropriate module was not put into the requirements.txt by PyCharm. I manually added it (Flask-SQLAlchemy~=3.1.1) and all works.
gunicorn~=23.0.0
psycopg~=3.2.3
psycopg2~=2.9.10
Flask~=3.1.0
SQLAlchemy~=2.0.36
Flask-SQLAlchemy~=3.1.1

